# Make parameters available to all functions inside Ramda's pipe function

Tags: functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm using `Ramda` in node with express. I have a standard route:

```
app.get('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) => {

}
```

Where I'd like to compose functions using Ramda, but I write these functions outside the route (so they will be reusable in other routes).
For example:

```
function extractParams() {
  return req.query.id;
}

function findXById(id) {
  return xs.find(el => el.id == id);
}

function success(answer) {
  return res.status(200).json(answer);
}
```

Now I want to compose those functions inside several routers. One of them will be:

```
app.get('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) => {
  return R.pipe(extractParams, findXById, success)();
}
```

Is there any way I can prepare a generic wrapper that wraps the request and response objects on the routers to be available to these functions? I guess I'll 
also have to change their signature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's really needed here is a version of `pipe` that accepts some initial arguments and returns a new function that will accept the remaining ones, with all the functions having such a dual-application signature.  I came up with the following `doublePipe` implementation that does this:

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => 
  pipe (...(map (pipe (apply, applyTo (initialArgs)), fns) ))


const foo = (x, y) => (z) => (x + y) * z
const bar = (x, y) => (z) => (x + y) * (z + 1)

const baz = doublePipe (foo, bar)

console .log (
  baz (2, 4) (1) //=> (2 + 4) * (((2 + 4) * 1) + 1) => 42
  //                   /    \    '------+----'
  //        bar ( x --/  ,   `-- y    ,  `-- z, which is foo (2, 4) (1) )
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {pipe, map, apply, applyTo} = R                </script>
```

Note that the functions `foo` and `bar` will both receive the same `x` and `y` arguments, and that `foo (x, y)` will receive the `z` argument supplied from the outside, with its result passed as `z` to `bar (x, y)`.

This is an interesting function, and it's a fairly useful generic solution to this sort of problem.  **But** it won't work in your Express environment, because the handlers need to have the signature `(req, res) => ...` and not `(req, res) => (...args) => ...`.

So below is an alternative, which mimics a trivial Express-like environment and uses a slightly different `doublePipe` version, which does not take an additional invocation, simply calling the first function with no parameters, and then sequentially passing the results through to the others as expected.  This means the first function to `doublePipe` must have the signature `(req, res) => () => ...`, while the others have `(req, res) => (val) => ...`.  While we could fix it so that that the first one was just `(req, res) => ...`, it seems to me that this inconsistency would not be helpful.

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => 
  reduce (applyTo, void 0, map (apply (__, initialArgs), fns))


const xs = [{id: 1, val: 'abc'}, {id: 2, val: 'def'},{id: 3, val: 'ghi'}, {id: 4, val: 'jkl'}]

const extractParams = (req, res) => () => req .query .id
const findXById = (xs) => (req, res) => (id) => xs .find (el => el .id == id)
const success = (req, res) => (answer) => res .status (200) .json (answer)

app .get ('/api/v1/tours', doublePipe (extractParams, findXById (xs), success))

console .log (
  app .invoke ('get', '/api/v1/tours?foo=bar&id=3')
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>

const {__, map, reduce, applyTo, apply, head, compose, split, objOf, fromPairs, last} = R

// Minimal version of Express, only enough for this demo

const base = compose (head, split ('?'))
const makeRequest = compose (objOf ('query'), fromPairs, map (split ('=')), split ('&'), last, split ('?'))
const makeResponse = () => {
  const response = {
    status: (val) => {response .status = val; return response},
    json: (val) => {response.body = JSON .stringify (val); delete response.json; return response}
  }
  return response
}
const app = {
  handlers: {get: {}, post: {}},
  get: (route, handler) => app .handlers .get [route] = handler,
  invoke: (method, route) => 
    app .handlers [method] [base (route)] (makeRequest (route), makeResponse ())
}


</script>
```

`findById` does not have the required signature, but `findById(xs)` does, so that's what we pass into `pipe`.

Finally, note that Ramda and Express may never play particularly well together, as the handlers sent to Express are meant to modify their parameters, and Ramda is designed to never mutate input data.  That said, this seems to work reasonably well for these requirements.

### Update: explanation of `doublePipe`

A comment seemed to indicate that a more complete description of `doublePipe` was in order.  I will only discuss the second version,

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => 
  reduce (applyTo, void 0, map (apply (__, initialArgs), fns))
```

Here are two possible calls:

```
// foo :: (a, b) -> f
const foo = doublePipe (
  f1, // :: (a, b) -> Void -> (c)
  f2, // :: (a, b) -> c -> d
  f3, // :: (a, b) -> d -> e
  f4, // :: (a, b) -> e -> f
)     

// bar :: (a, b, c) -> f
const bar = doublePipe (
  g1, // :: (a, b, c) -> Void -> d
  g2, // :: (a, b, c) -> d -> e
  g3, // :: (a, b, c) -> e -> f    
)
```

If you're not familiar with the Hindley-Milner signatures (such as `(a, b) -> c -> d` above), I wrote a [long article](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki/Type-Signatures) on the [Ramda wiki](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/wiki) about their uses in Ramda.  The `foo` function is built by passing `f1` - `f4` to `doublePipe`.  The resulting function takes parameters of types `a` and `b` (`req` and `res` in your example) and returns a value of type `f`.  Similarly `bar` is created by supplying `g1` - `g3` to `doublePipe`, returning a function that accepts parameters of types `a`, `b`, and `c` and returning a value of type `f`.

We can rewrite `doublePipe` a bit more imperatively to show the steps taken:

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => {
  const resultFns = map (apply (__, initialArgs), fns)
  return reduce (applyTo, void 0, resultFns)
}
```

and expanding that a bit, this might also look like

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => {
  const resultFns = map (fn => fn(...initialArgs), fns)
  return reduce ((value, fn) => fn (value), undefined, resultFns)
}
```

In the first line, we partially apply the initial arguments to each of the supplied functions, giving us a list of simpler functions.  For `foo` resultFns would look like `[f1(req, res), f2(req, res), f3(req, res), f4(req, res)]`, which would have signatures `[Void -> c, c -> d, d -> e, e -> f]`.  We could now choose to `pipe` those functions and call the resulting function (`return pipe(...resultFns)()`), but I didn't see a good reason to create the piped function only to call it a single time and throw it away, so I `reduce` over that list, starting with `undefined` and passing the result of each one to the next.

I tend to think in terms of Ramda functions, but you could write this easily enough without them:

```js
const doublePipe = (...fns) => (...initialArgs) => 
  fns 
    .map (fn => fn (...initialArgs))
    .reduce ((value, fn) => fn (value), void 0)
```

I hope this made that clearer!

Comment: Thank you very much! This is a monstrous and great answer that does exactly what I've asked. But, first I need to understand The `doublePipe` function better. In any case, I can't use It in production b/c I'm the only FP enthusiast around. I think a better Idea will be to use a handler function which will have the signature `(req, res) => <void>` and the actual logic will be composed of functions which will not contain the `req` and `res` objects (after extracting some kind of a shared DTO). This seems like a better pattern.

Comment: @MaxG: In FP, if logic functions need to query the `req` or `res` objects, they **must** be supplied as parameters.  They can be embedded in closures as above, or they can be wrapped up in a single data object, but they must be supplied as parameters.  If you want to thread a DTO through your functions, you can use a plain Ramda `pipe`, but then your functions will have to extract their relevant properties and return the altered DTO.  If you want to just call the functions with a continually-mutating DTO, I wouldn't use Ramda; it's the wrong tool for that sort of job.

Comment: @MaxG: Added an update to explain `doublePipe` more completely.

Answer (score 0):

Your three functions do not have the things they need in their declared scope. You need to modify their signature first:

```
function extractParams(req) { //<-- added `req`
  return req.query.id;
}

function findXById(id, xs) { //<-- added `xs`
  return xs.find(el => el.id == id);
}

function success(res, answer) { //<-- added `res`
  return res.status(200).json(answer);
}
```

Note that the order of the parameters isn't "random". The data you need to operate on should be the last as it allows for a nicer function composition experience. It's one of the tenet of Ramda:

> The parameters to Ramda functions are arranged to make it convenient for currying. The data to be operated on is generally supplied last.

Source: https://ramdajs.com/

This is not enough though. You need to curry some of them. Why? While the "recipe" of your function composition looks the same, each individual function operate on a specific data. This will make sense later, let's curry first:

```
const extractParams = (req) => req.query.id;
const findXById = R.curry((id, xs) => xs.find(el => el.id == id));
const success = R.curry((res, answer) => res.status(200).json(answer));
```

Now you can build a function composition whilst supplying some specific parameter to your functions in the composition:

```
app.get('/api/v1/tours', (req, res) =>
  R.pipe(
    extractParams,
    findXById(42),
    success(res))
      (req));
```

---

It's important to note that while there is nothing "wrong" with this, it's also missing the point:

```
R.pipe(extractParams, findXById, success)()
```

Why? `R.pipe` or `R.compose` (or `R.o`) returns a function composition which is itself a function that you call with parameters (just one with `R.o` but let's ignore that for now). So you need to think about the data that goes through your function composition. In your case it's probably `req`:

```
R.pipe(extractParams, findXById, success)(req)
```

Each function in your function composition receives as its parameter, the result of the previous function. If something in between doesn't depend on that, then *perhaps* that function shouldn't be part of the composition. (Take that advice with a pinch of salt; special conditions *may* apply; just think about it ;)

Comment: Thanks, your answer isn't 100% working but It got me going in the right direction.

Comment: I think your parameters to `findXById` are likely reversed.  I'm assuming that `xs` is available in scope before this function is invoked, but that `id` should be passed by the previous function.

Comment: I assumed that `xs` would have been returned by `req.query.id` in this case. But that's probably a poor assumption.